# UITableViewCell inside a StackView without TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an tableView (A), and in one of my cells (B) I want to load another cell (C). I started creating a tableView (D) inside that cell (B) and including the cell (C) inside this tableView (D).

The visual explanation:

[image]

But I read that it ins't a good practice to place a tableView inside another, so I'm removing the tableView (D) and trying to work with an stackView. I will have a StackView inside the first cell (B) that will contain the others cells (D and others).

Is it possible? I tried this:

```
    let cellView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(someCell.identifier, owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as? UIView
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(cellView!)
```

But the cell isn't presented in my view. There's some way to this cell inside another cell without creating a new tableView there? Is it a good practice, or should I create the tableView (D) inside the cell (B)?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just create a UIView instead of using a UITableViewCell?

Comment: Yes. There is. i'm already using this cell in the table, as a cell. I can convert it to a View, but I will need to create a cell with this view inside anyway and it make sense being a cell.

Comment: Use a UIView, embed it in both cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do that.

Table view cells are not meant to be used outside of a table view, and all bets are off if you try to do that.

Why in the world would you want a table view cell that's not part of a table view?

Comment: Because I have an cell (A) that I need to use inside another cell (B). It's already working. But I had to create a tableView inside the cell B to insert the cell A. It seems that create a tableView inside a cell is a bad practice

Comment: I edited my question explaning visually what I wanna do. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 1):

`UITableViewCell` is only meant to be used as a subview of a UITableView.

Instead, you would want to consider changing your **Cell C** class to be a subclass of `UIView` instead and just add it as a subview of the `contentView` of **Cell B** or as an arranged subview of your `UIStackView`.